# In R package tesseract ORC number and string failed

Tags: r, tesseract

There `1_.png` file as attached image, how can I get the tracking number `1Z 128 1W1 03 4990 0557` in this image ?  Useing `tesseract` can't get this part

```
library("tesseract")
mtext <- ocr("1_.png")
cat(mtext)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can preprocess the image before using `ocr` with `magick`:

```r
library(magick)
#> Linking to ImageMagick 7.1.0.31
#> Enabled features: cairo, fontconfig, freetype, heic, lcms, pango, raw, rsvg, webp, x11
#> Disabled features: fftw, ghostscript
#> Using 12 threads
library(tesseract)
input <- image_read("https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLOo1.png") %>% 
  image_convert(type = 'Grayscale') %>% 
  image_rotate(90) %>% 
  image_deskew() %>% 
  image_resize("2000x")

input
```

[image]

I found that the most important change is to scale up the image (probably you could also change a setting in `tesseract` to read smaller fonts, but I couldn't find it). After this is done, it works fine:

```r
ocr(input) %>% 
  strsplit("\n") %>%
  unlist() %>% 
  grep("TRACKING", ., value = TRUE) 
#> [1] "£ TRACKING #: 1Z 128 1W1 (3 4990 0557"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

This looks good except the 0 which is read as an "(". But I don't think you can get a better result using the low res input.

Comment: I tried the result show  character(0) ,  but i tried another  png file ,it's ok. I don't why

Comment: That's strange. Did you use the same code or did you load the png from disk? Have you tried without the `grep` line to see what `ocr` produces?

Comment: change   image_resize("2000x")  can get the tracking number 。 Another question:  when I want to get reference No.1 and No.2  in the botton in small font size, it's failed even change resize to a large number, Could you help on this ? Thanks!

Comment: I think the resolution of the original image is just not high enough. Even scaled up, I can only guess most of the characters.

Comment: Thanks , improve the quantily of original can solve it (Ocr ok now)